# How to use PHP str_replace to replace values started with $

Tags: php

I am making feed functionality in my website, where users can actions can be diplayed.

I am storing different actions messages as

```
 {item:$user} added {var:$count} photo(s) to the album {item:$album_name}
```

in the database , because i have get different action messages at run time.

**So when i am using str_replace as**

```
$body =  "{item:$user} added {var:$count} photo(s) to the album {item:$album_name}";

$body =  str_replace("{item:$user}",$userName,$body);
```

**Its not replacing the text and displaying as it is, but when i remove the "$user}" its replacing the string "{item:".**

Is there any issue in my script or i have to use some special method.

Thanks.

Comment: -1 because asking questions at SO requires minimum understanding of the topic. How can one code something in PHP without basic knowledge about it? Having `$blah = "something";` subsequent string `"$blah aaa"` will change into `"something aaa"`. Use single quotes `'$blah aaa'` to keep this string untouched.

Answer (score 2):

When PHP parses your str_replace statement, since your "{item:$user}" is in double quotes, PHP will attempt to evaluate both variables and functions within the string before returning the string. So it is looking for $user thinking it is a variable. Try replacing the double quotes with single quotes and seeing what that does.

I would also suggest making your template placeholders simpler is you are just using string replace with the needle hard coded. In your example {user} would also work instead of {var:$user}. Or change your replacement method to take advantage of the multiple part placeholders

Comment: Thanks @Robert the replacement of double quote with single quote works.

Comment: Sweet, marking me as an answer much appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing this:

```
var $s = "$variable inside a string"
```

simply do this (single quotes):

```
var $s = '$variable inside a string'
```

This way it won't substitute the variable in the string with its value. When you use double quotes, the variable inside your string will be replaces with its value.

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes:

```
$body =  str_replace('{item:$user}',$userName,$body);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also going to give you the same answers as others:

```
$var = 'EXAMPLE';
// double quotes take a string with variables, but interprents them 'gently'
echo " this is $var "; // will result in [ this is EXAMPLE ]

// Single quotes all a litteral string. This means it will not _parse_ the values (or functions)
echo ' this is $var '; // will result in [ this is $var ]

// If you want the dolarsign AND doublequotes, you have to escape
echo " this is \$var "; // will result in [ this is $var]
```

Comment: your answer didn't cover single quotes

Comment: Thanks, fixed it. The singlequote example now actually has single quotes